# ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement- when run a procedure in oracle 10g

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, ide, procedure

I am using Oracle 10g database and trying to run a procedure using SQL commands.

```
create or replace procedure "exam" is
begin
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Test');
end;
```

Then click on Run button. It shows: "procedure created".

When I try to execute it using:

```
execute exam;
```

then click on Run button, it shows:

```
ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Just noticed a detail in your question. You press `run` button. Thus, you must be using an IDE.

You cannot use `execute` in IDEs - it is an `sql*plus` command. It *might* work in Oracle SQL Developer though, but I wouldn't use it there anyway;

Try

```
begin
  exam;
end;
```

Comment: if you quote your procedure name, then you should also quote procedure call. if you do not - don't quote in both places.

Comment: try `create or replace exam... `, `execute exam;` (no quotes)

Answer (score 1):

See: [Syntax error while trying to call an Oracle package using ODBC in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18837539/syntax-error-while-trying-to-call-an-oracle-package-using-odbc-in-c-sharp)

You have to put "{" and "}" before the command.
Example:

```
    processListCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    processListCmd.CommandText = "{ call rep_invnr_proclist }";
    processListCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: the question is not related to C#

Comment: @Line You are absolutely right! Probably I got confused with too many browser tabs opened and picked the wrong tab when answering.

Comment: Actually, this may be the correct answer. Since, as @kirill-leontev pointed out, @kumar seems not to be using SQL*Plus, using `{ call ... }` instead of `exec ...` should work better.

Answer (score 0):

Lose the double-quotes around the name. They're a bad practice in Oracle.

Comment: when used: create or replace procedure exam is begin DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Test'); end; same error is coming.

Comment: Must be the way that you're executing it in whatever tool you're using then. Does it work in SQL*Plus? If not, you may be executing it as SQL instead of as a procedure call.

Comment: that should be rather a comment, it does not provide the solution in my opinion