# Amazon RDS(Oracle 12c): ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, oracle12c

I am trying to alter the default temporary space by executing the following commands.

```
exec rdsadmin.rdsadmin_util.alter_default_temp_tablespace(tablespace_name => 'temp01');
BEGIN rdsadmin.rdsadmin_util.alter_default_temp_tablespace(tablespace_name => 'temp01') END;
```

but getting "ORA-00900" error.

How can I get this to work?

Comment: Can you try with `begin <statement> end; /` block. As explained in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13722307/ora-00900-invalid-sql-statement-when-run-a-procedure-in-oracle-10g) the `exec` command is specific to `sql*plus` and may not work in online IDE.

Comment: I tried that, it did not work either.