# how to connect a user in procedure?

Tags: sql, oracle

I created a procedure that into it, the procedure, connect to a database. 
but when I run it, I gave an error:

> ora-00900: invalid SQL statement

my procedure is below:

```
create or replace procedure check_p
as
st:='connect xx/xxx@databasename';
execute immediate st;

end;
/
```

please help me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement- when run a procedure in oracle 10g](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13722307/ora-00900-invalid-sql-statement-when-run-a-procedure-in-oracle-10g)

Comment: What is it that you actually want to do? Stored procedures exist on the database server so they are already connected to a database. If you want to access a different database the canonical thing to do would be to use a database link. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/ds_concepts002.htm#ADMIN12083